# Condition ngIf while displaying

Tags: angular

I have a div that i want to append an ngIf condition on date.

At the moment i'm displaying all the dates like this:

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of users">
        <div *ngIf="user.recipient === selectedUser._id && showUser(user)">
          <div *ngIf="shouldDisplayDate(user.date)">
          <div class="message-date">{{ user.date | date:'EEEE'}} {{user.date | date:'d'}}  {{ user.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ user.date |
            date:'yyyy'}}
          </div>
          </div>
```

As Example :

```
["Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:21:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:03:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:01:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:53:23 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 08:52:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:49 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:42 GMT+0200 (CEST)"]
```

I have 6 Times Fri 13 Jul + 3 Times Thu 12 July and one time Mon 16 Jul

I want to only display the first one of every date and not all of them

```
"Thu Jul 12 2018 13:41:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
"Mon Jul 16 2018 11:40:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
 "Fri Jul 13 2018 09:33:46 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
```

I managed to get the above result with this function, but i think it need refactor.
the ts

```
 shouldDisplayDate(date: Date) {
const arrayDate = this.users.map(a => a.date);
const set = new Set()
const filtreArrayDate = arrayDate.filter((a) => {
  const d = new Date(a).setHours(0, 0, 0)
  if (set.has(d)) {
    return false
  }
  set.add(d);
  return true;
})
```

}

Is there a way to do an ngIf so i can only display the value which are in the filtreArrayDate and call correctly my function so i can display only the value which are in the filtredArrayDate?

Thank you.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest

Comment: do you want to support dynamic filters ? 
So can the list change over time ?

Comment: so you want each date of dates which is multiple and that should not be repeated??

Comment: @DanielHoppeAlvarez   At the moment my only problem is in the html, didn't kno how to do the ngIF, the function is working like a charm, i want to display the value that is available in the filtredArrayDate

Comment: can you set up a stackblitz ?

Comment: @DanielHoppeAlvarez 
StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stacktest

Comment: The two first lines are already incorrect: `let user of user`: don't use the same variable for the **array of users** (note the plural form), and for each element of this array. `showUser(User)`: your variable is named User, not user.

Comment: Edited it, my problem is in the html file, because the function is returning me the filtred array i want to check if the date is in the array or not, if it's in the array i display if not i don't

Comment: Stackblitz not working at all. Please check

Comment: @NiteshRana Didn't know how to do the ngIf/ngFor so i can display only the filtred Date

Comment: It's not showing anything on ui. Not even date. Please check

Comment: @NiteshRana Please check now

Comment: What I understood from your question is you want unique dates only in UI to show. Am i right

Comment: @NiteshRana Yeeeeeeeeeeeeees that's it